# Initial algebra for natural numbers

Tags: haskell, recursion, algebraic-data-types, category-theory, catamorphism

I'm trying to make sure I understand the initial algebra and catamorphism concept using the basic case of natural numbers, but I'm definitely missing something (also my Haskell syntax might be a mess).

**A later edit**

I think my problem is mainly related to the functions `Fx` / `unFix` that define the isomorphism between `NatF (Fix NatF)` and `Fix NatF`. My understanding is that `Fix NatF` is **N** (the set of natural numbers), that is `Nat = Zero | Succ Nat`.

How is `Fx` exactly defined? Is this correct?

```
Fx ZeroF = Zero
Fx (SuccF ZeroF) = Succ (Fx ZeroF) = Succ (Zero)
```

If so, why isn't this the same as the initial algebra **1 + N -> N** evaluated by the pair **[0, succ]**?

---

**Original Post**

I know that for natural numbers we have the functor **F(U) = 1 + U** and the initial algebra **F(U) -> U** where **unit** goes to **0** and **n** goes to **succ(n) = n + 1**. For another algebra evaluated by a function **h**, the catamorphism **cata** will be **cata(n) = h<sup>n</sup>(unit)**.

So can write the functor as `data NatF a = ZeroF | SuccF a` and it's fixed point as `data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat`

I guess then we could define `Fx :: NatF (Fix NatF) -> Fix NatF` or say `Fix NatF = Fx (NatF (Fix NatF))`

If we define another algebra with carrier type `String` like this

```
h :: NatF String -> String
h ZeroF  = "0"
h (SuccF x) = x ++ " + 1"
```

then I think we could use `cata h = h . fmap (cata h) . unFix` for a natural number like 1, as below

```
(h . fmap (cata h) . unFix) Fx(SuccF Fx(ZeroF)) =
(h . fmap (cata h)) (SuccF Fx(ZeroF)) =
h (SuccF (cata h)(Fx(ZeroF))) =
h(SuccF h(ZeroF)) =
h (SuccF "0") =
"0 + 1"
```

But this does not seem to be the formula **cata(n) = h<sup>n</sup>(unit)**. Where is my mistake in all this?

Comment: `Fx` is defined generically for any functor: `newtype Fix f = Fx { unFix :: f (Fix f)}`. Then `Fx ZeroF` is isomorphic to `Zero`; `Fx (SuccF (Fx ZeroF))` to `Succ Zero`; etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your confusion has to do with **cata(n)=h<sup>n</sup>(unit)**.  This isn't true -- you have an off-by-one error.  In particular, consider the defining commutative diagram for the initial algebra `nat :: 1 + Nat -> Nat`:

```
          nat
1 + Nat  --->   Nat

  |              |
  | F(cata)      |  cata
  V              V
          h
1 + A    --->    A
```

This gives the following, with Haskell-like "type annotations" for the arguments, to make it clearer what we're doing:

```
cata(0 :: Nat)
-- by definition of nat(unit)
= cata(nat(unit :: 1 + Nat) :: Nat)
-- by diagram
= h(F(cata)(unit :: 1 + Nat) :: 1 + A)
-- as F(cata)(unit) = unit
= h(unit :: 1 + A)
```

So, you *actually* have **cata(0)=h<sup>1</sup>(unit)**.  The appropriate general formula is **cata(n)=h<sup>n+1</sup>(unit)**.

Comment: Hmm... am I misreading this? 
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.37.1418&rep=rep1&type=pdf
end of page 15, and start of page 16

Comment: Yes, **u** in that article isn't unit.  It's the zero-like element in **U**, namely, **u=h(unit)**, so the bottom of page 15 actually says **f(n)=h^n(h(unit))**.  It goes back to @chi's answer, and the dual role of **h** in your representation.

Comment: Wow... you are right... u is not unit, that incidentally start with an 'u'. Comments should not be for thanks, but still... thank you! It's so easy to get confused by all this!

Answer (score 2):

An algebra `NatF A -> A` is made of (up to isomorphism)

- the type `A`
- a constant `z :: A` (you call this "unit")
- a function `s :: A -> A` (you call this "h")

Then, informally, `cata algebra n = s^n(z)`.

In your example, `h` is

```
h :: NatF String -> String
h ZeroF  = "0"
h (SuccF x) = x ++ " + 1"
```

but this is the whole algebra (`z` and `s`), not just the `s` morphism.

Your `h` above corresponds to this:

- `A = String`
- `z = "0"`
- `s x = x ++ " + 1"`

And indeed, (in informal notation) `cata h 1 = s^1(z) = s z = "0" ++ " + 1" = "0 + 1"`.

Conclusion: don't use `h` to call both the algebra and the morphism `s` which is "inside" the algebra.

Comment: My biggest confusion is probably related to the fact that `Fix :: NatF (Fix NatF) -> Fix NatF` is the same as [0, succ] :: 1 + N -> N. Does `Fix ZeroF = ZeroF` and corresponds to 0 in N and `Fix (SuccF ZeroF) = SuccF (Fix ZeroF) = SuccF ZeroF` and corresponds to 1 in N?

Comment: I agree on the first sentence. About the second one: the equation `Fix ZeroF = ZeroF` is not technically true: the LHS is of type `Fix NatF`, the RHS of type `NatF a` for any `a`.

Comment: @jackmalkovick Also note that `1+N -> N` is isomorphic to `N * (N -> N)`. In a general algebra, `A * (A -> A)` hence the `(z,s)` pair I describe above.

Comment: I've added a later edit. I hope it does not change the idea of the post. I tried to make it clear at least to myself what bothers me...

Comment: @jackmalkovick You can't really define the `Fx` iso in Haskell: it's auto-generated by the `newtype Fix f = ...` definition. Consider the simpler `newtype B = Biso Bool` which is isomorphic to `Bool`. You can't really define `Biso`: the equation `Biso True = Biso True` is not really a meaningful definition. The `newtype` definition essentially postulates the isomorphism (in your case, the existence of the initial algebra).